# How can I compare all the titles of all RSS feeds and delete duplicates?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm wondering if there is a way to compare `ALL TITLES in ALL RSS FEEDS` and delete the duplicates.

I read through a lot of `RSS` Feeds, and it's obvious that a lot of people cross-post to several forums, and then I end up seeing the same `RSS` Feed multiple times.

I think the script will look something like this, but it doesn't seem to delete dupes.....

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub DupeRSS()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim RSS_Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set RSS_Folder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderRssFeeds)

    'Process Current Folder
    Example RSS_Folder
End Sub
Public Sub Example(ByVal ParentFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder)
    Dim itm As Object, itms As Items, dupes As Object, i As Long, k As Variant

    Set dupes = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set itms = ParentFolder.Items

    For i = itms.Folders.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set itm = itms(i)
        If TypeOf itm Is PostItem Then
            If dupes.Exists(itm.Subject) Then itm.Delete Else dupes(itm.Subject) = 0
        Else
            Example itm     'Recursive call for Folders
        End If
    Next i

    'Show dictionary items
    If dupes.Count > 0 Then
        For Each k In dupes
            Debug.Print k
        Next
    End If

    Set itm = Nothing:  Set itms = Nothing: Set dupes = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]

Thanks to all!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Maybe this is what your trying to do, the following code saves/adds all the Items subject line to the collection and then continues to search multiple folders and then deletes if it finds duplicates-*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub DupeRSS()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim RSS_Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim DupItem As Object

    Set DupItem = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set RSS_Folder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderRssFeeds)

'   // Process Current Folder
    Example RSS_Folder, DupItem
End Sub
Public Sub Example(ByVal ParentFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder, _
                   ByVal DupItem As Object)
    Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Items As Items
    Dim i As Long

    Set Items = ParentFolder.Items
    Debug.Print ParentFolder.Name

    For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        DoEvents

        If TypeOf Items(i) Is PostItem Then
            Set Item = Items(i)
            If DupItem.Exists(Item.Subject) Then
                Debug.Print Item.Subject ' Print on Immediate Window
                Debug.Print TypeName(Item) ' Print on Immediate Window
                Item.Delete
            Else
                DupItem.Add Item.Subject, 0
                Debug.Print DupItem.Count, Item.Subject
            End If
        End If

    Next i

'   // Recurse through subfolders
    If ParentFolder.Folders.Count > 0 Then
        For Each Folder In ParentFolder.Folders
            Example Folder, DupItem
            Debug.Print Folder.Name
        Next
    End If

    Set Folder = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing
    Set Items = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Ahhhhhh!  This is a beautiful thing!!  This does exactly what I want!!  Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the changes bellow

---

```
Option Explicit

'Required - VBA Editor -> Tools -> References: Microsfot Outlook XXX Object Library
'Required - VBA Editor -> Tools -> References: Microsfot Scripting Runtime (Dictionary)

Public Sub RemoveRSSduplicates()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace, olApp As Object, rssFolder As Folder, d As Dictionary

    Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set rssFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderRssFeeds)
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ProcessOutlookRSSFeeds rssFolder, d
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub ProcessOutlookRSSFeeds(ByVal rssFolder As Folder, ByRef d As Dictionary)
    Dim fldr As Folder, itm As Object

    For Each fldr In rssFolder.Folders
        If fldr.Items.Count > 0 Then
            For Each itm In fldr.Items
                If TypeOf itm Is PostItem Then
                    If Not d.Exists(itm.Subject) Then d(itm.Subject) = 0 Else itm.Delete
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Note: avoid variable names that will hide other objects (ex. `Dim Items As Items`)

Comment: This is very weird.  Now, I get an error on this line: For i = itms.Folders.Count To 1 Step -1.  The error message reads: Object doesn't support this property or method. I just updated all the code I have now.

Comment: It seems like it is looping through all folders, and all subjects in each folder, but as soon as the focus goes from one folder to the next, all the subjects in the prior folder are lost, so this will never find any dupes.  I believe that was the initial problem, and it seems to be the same now.  Ugh.  Any other ideas?  Thanks.