# Move old email in conversation to subfolder

Tags: vba, outlook

I am looking for a macro to move earlier email in a conversation (sorted by subject) to a subfolder, except the latest conversation in that subject.

Upon receiving a new mail on the same conversation, then move the older email to subfolder.

I found the base to move emails older than 7 days, but not sure how to move older conversations and leave only the latest mail.

```vb
Sub MoveAgedMail()

    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objSourceFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Dim objVariant As Variant
    Dim lngMovedItems As Long
    Dim intCount As Integer
    Dim intDateDiff As Integer
    Dim strDestFolder As String   

    Set objOutlook = Application
    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    'Set objSourceFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set objSourceFolder = objNamespace.Folders("Online Archive - OTCGROUP@abc.ssmb.com").Folders("Inbox").Folders("DEST1")

    ' use a subfolder under Inbox
    'Set objDestFolder = objSourceFolder.Folders("DEST")
     Set objDestFolder = objNamespace.Folders("Online Archive - OTCGROUP2@abc.ssmb.com").Folders("Inbox").Folders("DEST2")

    For intCount = objSourceFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1

        Set objVariant = objSourceFolder.Items.Item(intCount)
        DoEvents

        If objVariant.Class = olMail Then

             intDateDiff = DateDiff("d", objVariant.SentOn, Now)

            ' I'm using 7 days, adjust as needed.
            If intDateDiff > 7 Then
              objVariant.Move objDestFolder

              'count the # of items moved
               lngMovedItems = lngMovedItems + 1
            End If

        End If

    Next

    ' Display the number of items that were moved.
    MsgBox "Moved " & lngMovedItems & " messages(s)."

Set objDestFolder = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: for duplicates subject? - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46166631/4539709

Comment: @0m3r : Thanks. The link you provided is deleting the duplicates, but not sure how it will decide which of the thread to retain.
I wanted to retain/ignore the latest of the thread in the DUP_TEST and move rest of the earlier emails of the same thread to DES_TEST.
By any chance can we use 'Thread-Topic' ot ' Thread-Index'.

I tried below but i dont see the mail move to DES_TEST folder.
`Public Sub Dup()
    Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Items As Items
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Dup_Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder`

Comment: @0m3r : `'Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Dup_Folder = olNs.Folders("lj21786@imcnam.ssmb.com").Folders("Inbox").Folders("DUP_TEST")
    Set Des_Folder = olNs.Folders("lj21786@imcnam.ssmb.com").Folders("Inbox").Folders("DES_TEST")
    Set Items = Dup_Folder.Items
    Debug.Print Dup_Folder.Name

    For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        DoEvents
       If TypeOf Items(i) Is PostItem Then
            Set Item = Items(i)
            If DupItem.Exists(Item.Subject) Then`

Comment: `Set Item = Items(i)
          If DupItem.Exists(Item.Subject) Then
                Debug.Print Item.Subject ' Print on Immediate Window
                Debug.Print TypeName(Item) ' Print on Immediate Window
                'Item.Delete
                Item.Move Des_Folder
            Else
                DupItem.Add Item.Subject, 0
                Debug.Print DupItem.Count, Item.Subject
            End If
        End If

    Next i
    'End If
'MsgBox "Moved " & Item.Subject & " messages(s)."

    Set Folder = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing
    Set Items = Nothing
End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through all items in the folder is not really a good idea:

```
 For intCount = objSourceFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set objVariant = objSourceFolder.Items.Item(intCount)
```

Use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class instead. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Comment: Thanks . For now, i am able to move the emails through below code but getting error  "Method 'ReceivedTime' of object '_MailItem' failed” on debug its on line "comparisonItemAge=today - mItem.ReceivedTime.

`Dim nSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim targetFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim desFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim mItem As MailItem
Dim comparisonItem As MailItem
Dim tempSubject As String
Dim today As Date
Private Sub Application_NewMail()
Set nSpace = GetNamespace("MAPI")
`

Comment: `Set targetFolder = nSpace.Folders("Lijo").Folders("Inbox").Folders("TAR_TEST")
Set desFolder = nSpace.Folders("Lijo").Folders("Inbox").Folders("DES_TEST")

For Each mItem In targetFolder.Items
tempSubject = mItem.Subject
    While InStr(1, Left(tempSubject, 3), "RE:") > 0 Or InStr(1, Left(tempSubject, 4), "FW:") > 0
        tempSubject = Mid(tempSubject, 5)
    Wend
    
    For Each comparisonItem In targetFolder.Items
        If InStr(1, comparisonItem.Subject, tempSubject) > 0 Then
            today = Now()
            `

Comment: `currentItemAge = today - comparisonItem.ReceivedTime
            comparisonItemAge = today - mItem.ReceivedTime
            If currentItemAge < comparisonItemAge Then
                mItem.Move desFolder
                Exit For
            End If
            
            If currentItemAge > comparisonItemAge Then
                comparisonItem.Move desFolder
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
  Next

Set targetFolder = Nothing
Set desFolder = Nothing
Set nSpace = Nothing
End Sub
`